# How to find that website is using feeds or not?

Tags: c#, feed

Is there any way I could check that,given site(any) is using feeds or not,I'd seen www.bbc.co.uk is using feeds.I am using c# asp.net 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for this tag in the head section (this is for an atom feed):

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="link/address/" >`

For example BBC makes it known that they have a feed using this (they have an RSS feed):

`<link href="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="BBC News - Home" />`

Comment: thanks for answering my question,but It doesnt work with yahoo news,any idea??why so??

Comment: @konika Yahoo doesn't seem to provide a standard way to broadcast their RSS/Atom feeds. but they are [here](http://news.yahoo.com/sitemap/) on a single page.